# How to implement AsyncTask in my code.?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am a beginner in android and programming in general and I have a personal project relating to my work, which is basically a set of queries to an existing database.

One of the queries takes too long and I need to implement the method asyntask and put a loading in screen. I've read various examples(complexes and complicates) but I can not implement in my project, so I come here to ask the community for help, to guide me in the correct placement of the code

In short, this is my code

This is my main activity, with a button click event and two edittext two search.

```
Button button = (Button)vendas.findViewById(R.id.pesquisa);
        Button button1 = (Button)vendas.findViewById(R.id.ven_revisoes);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VendasActivity.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) vendas.findViewById(R.id.edittxt2);
            EditText editText1 = (EditText) vendas.findViewById(R.id.edittxt1);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            String message1 = editText1.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, message1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

my VendasActivity.class where I have to implement AsyncTask and loading message

```
VendasDataSource datasource;
private List<Venda> vendas;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_vendas);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Vendas.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(Vendas.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);

    datasource = new VendasDataSource(this); // datasource class
    datasource.open();


vendas = datasource.find("Select.... // my long query

//my custom list

ArrayAdapter<Venda> adapter = new VendaListAdapter(this, vendas);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

my datasource class

```
public List<Venda> find(String select) {

    String query = (select);

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned " + cursor.getCount() + " rows");

    List<Venda> vendas = cursorToList(cursor);
    return vendas;
}

private List<Venda> cursorToList(Cursor cursor) { // MY LIST
    List<Venda> vendas = new ArrayList<Venda>();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Venda venda = new Venda();

                     venda.setid(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex.......
vendas.add(venda);
        }
    }

    return vendas;
}
```

Where do I put the code of AsyncTask... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **VendasActivity** you should create & execute the AsyncTask (lets call it *DataAsyncTask*):

```
 DataAsyncTask dataAsyncTask = new DataAsyncTask();
 dataAsyncTask.execute(query); //query is your query string
```

The DataAsyncTask should be a **inner class of VendasActivity** and will have more or less this structure (assuming you want it to output a `List<Venda>` once it finished:

```
 private class DataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Venda>> {

      protected List<Venda> doInBackground(String... query) {
            String queryString = query[0];

            //TODO: add your long running database code here...
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(List<Venda> vendaList) {

           Log.i(LOGTAG, "vendaList: " + vendaList);
      }
 }
```

For more details I recommend reading the documentation of [AsyncTask here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29)

Comment: ok thanks. I've been trying but I have too many errors. I will try later or put down. Regards